# Using Fourier analysis to check if data is oscillating

Tags: r, simulation

A simulation gives the population numbers for every species in the domain per frame. These vary over time and can be quite noisy, for example we might have:

Species A: `1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

Species B: `5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4`

Fourier analysis gives:

Species A

```
[1]  31.0000000+0i -11.3435375+0i   0.7284459+0i  -0.4486906+0i
[5]   0.6467467+0i   0.4170355+0i   0.4170355+0i   0.6467467+0i
[9]  -0.4486906+0i   0.7284459+0i -11.3435375+0i
```

Species B

```
[1] 31.0000000+0.0000000i  7.7083901-1.7455710i  2.5347604+1.2715540i
[4]  0.0859162+0.3689912i  1.8966739-0.8223734i -0.2257406+0.1538824i
[7] -0.2257406-0.1538824i  1.8966739+0.8223734i  0.0859162-0.3689912i
[10]  2.5347604-1.2715540i  7.7083901+1.7455710i
```

How can I use this to give an idea if they are oscillating?

I wish to somehow use this in a genetic algorithm as the fitness function to see how close each dataset is to oscillating.

Comment: aah, I see this was produced in R :-) using `fft(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1))` and `fft(c(5,4,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,3,4))`.

Comment: yes, although I need to find an equivalent method in java..

Comment: Once you get into the principle I think you will easily find a solution in any language. Also, R can be called from within many languages.

Comment: OK, I see. What could be the problem here that the species population index is not precisely known (??? I suppose??) but also has its own uncertainty. And this uncertainty is not taken into account here. I'm afraid that you have to take it into account if you want to assess the significance of oscillation of particular species. Or you would have to have a long time series to separate the real oscillation from random one, +15 years AT LEAST I'd say ...

Comment: species population index? What I would like to do is set a load of parameters for each species in a predator prey model and see if I can get them to live together without killing each other completely off hence the oscillation. Instead of setting the parameters manually I can use a genetic algorithm to search for me by tweaking the parameters. However I do need a fitness function for this to select which set of parameters is performing the best. This is the reason why I wanted to check if it was oscillating and have a single value that denotes how well it is

Comment: I think this should be migrated to the statistics site.  There are many aspects of answering this question that are statistical in nature, but not really programming in nature.  For populations, one might want to look at both trending and seasonal patterns, such as expansion/contraction cycles.  There are some stats folks who can help address that with standard methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [1] term is the zero frequency term- i.e. it's the mean.  It does not denote oscillation.  Any other strong terms do denote oscillation.  The [2] term, and it's complement at [11], denotes low-frequency oscillation.  You can see that in the time series by noting that Species A starts low, grows big, then goes low again.  Species B is the inverse.

Edit: After thinking about this a little more, it would probably be better to use auto-correlation (Google it if you don't know what it is) to find periodicity rather than Fourier transforms.  Auto-correlation will detect any kind of periodicity, not just sinusoidal tones, and would probably be more appropriate for large data sets.

Comment: thanks, if I analysed the data with an algorithm, would it be possible to get a single value of how close the data is to a perfect oscillation? And is the [1] term not the sum of all the components?

Comment: @Sycren A perfect oscillation would be where the first term is something positive (at least in your population case, in the more general case the first term could be zero), and all of the other terms are zero except for two- the tone complements.  The easiest way to see what I'm talking about is to create a sine wave (or cosine) and calculate its Fourier transform.

Comment: @Sycren Also, please note that the other terms can only be perfectly zero in theory- in any real data series they will be small, but they will be non-zero.

Comment: Can you think of any way of comparing the results from fourier with that of a sine graph to give a value denoting its similarity?

Comment: @Sycren I would compare the energy (element times its complement) in the tone terms in the Fourier series to the energy in the other terms.  That ratio would give you a single number.

Comment: @Sycren No, the [1] term is not the sum of the other terms.  It is the average of the time-domain terms.

Comment: so would I be able to get a single number from the ratio for the entire dataset? Or do you mean per element?

Comment: @Sycren You could do a ratio like "energy of top sinuosoid complement" / "sum of energies of all other terms"

Comment: Thank you for all the help, would you be able to give an example of what you mean with the data above?

Comment: If only a *perfectly sinusoidal* oscillation occurs then indeed all terms except the 1st and one other term will be (near) zero, but other types of periodic oscillation (e.g. a square wave) will have additional nonzero frequency components.  But I think they usually have a dominant frequency with smaller higher frequency components (square waves do at least), so Jim's ratio of "top term" / "all other terms" should still be a good test.

Comment: This is what the data is like: http://pastebin.com/uUbcN6k0 There are nearly 300 entries here but normally I would have around 10,000. The first column is time, 2nd species 1, 3rd species 2. My examples above were quite simplistic but would they also work for the data you see in the link?

Comment: @Sycren Yes, the method that I described will work for the data you have linked to.  It will also work for 10,000 points, or whatever.  What will change is that you FFT all of the species data points, and you will have as many points coming out of the FFT as you put into it.